# firebug / devtools: examine the value of variables on a third-party site?

Tags: javascript, firebug, developer-tools

Is it possible to examine the value of JavaScript variables on a third-party site?

For example, if I look at http://www.google.co.uk/ in Firebug or Developer Tools, I can see that the page loads a script called `content.js`, and within this script there is a variable called `link`.

Is there any way I can dump the value of that variable to the console, without edit access to the script itself.

I don't need to see the value at different points in page load - after the page has finished rendering is fine.

Comment: what happens if you open the console and just enter `link`? edit: it will come up as undefined. i don't see a content.js included...

Comment: I think the `content.js` is not from Google but from a Google Chrome extension you installed. As far as I know you can't print the variables of extension scripts into the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug, Chrome/Safari Web Inspector, IE9's F12 and Opera Dragonfly allow you to set breakpoints and inspect variables live.
After that you only need to reload the page.

With Opera Dragonfly (my main debugger) you can also simply set up "Break at the beginning of new scripts".

Comment: Oh yes, setting a breakpoint works - for some reason I thought you could only do this on local scripts. Thanks!